# How can I remove duplicate tuples from a list based on index value of tuple while maintaining the order of tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove those tuples which had same values at index 0 except the first occurance. I looked at other similar questions but did not get a particular answer I am looking for. Can somebody please help me?
Below is what I tried.

```
from itertools import groupby
import random
Newlist = []

abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,0,3),(0,2,0), (2,4,5),(5,4,3), (0,4,1)]

Newlist = [random.choice(tuple(g)) for _, g in groupby(abc, key=lambda x: x[0])]
print Newlist
```

my expected output : `[(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (0,2,0), (5,4,3)]`

Comment: With the `random.choice`, how can your attempt guarantee that it only keeps the first occurence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is to loop over the list and keep track of which elements you've already found:

```
abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,0,3),(0,2,0), (2,4,5),(5,4,3), (0,4,1)]
found = set()
NewList = []
for a in abc:
    if a[0] not in found:
        NewList.append(a)
    found.add(a[0])
print(NewList)
#[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

`found` is a `set`. At each iteration we check if the first element in the tuple is already in `found`. If not, we append the whole tuple to `NewList`. At the end of each iteration we add the first element of the tuple to `found`.

Comment: One caveat is that this only works if the first element of the tuple is hashable (which numbers, like in the given example, are, of course).

Comment: A slight improvement: only add `a[0]` to `found` if it is not already in there (i.e. increase the indentation by one level for `found.add(a[0])`).

Comment: it will be better to `continue` if `a[0]` in `found` & append/add otherwise (no indentation problem as @JackTaylor stated)

Comment: Thank you @pault: I am using this solution on my code.

Answer (score 3):

A better alternative using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,0,3), (0,2,0), (2,4,5),(5,4,3), (0,4,1)]
d = OrderedDict()
for t in abc:
    d.setdefault(t[0], t)
abc_unique = list(d.values())
print(abc_unique)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

---

Simple although not very efficient:

```
abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,0,3), (0,2,0), (2,4,5),(5,4,3), (0,4,1)]
abc_unique = [t for i, t in enumerate(abc) if not any(t[0] == p[0] for p in abc[:i])]
print(abc_unique)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

Comment: @ jdehesa: Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 3):

The [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (Python 2: [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes), but basically no difference in this case) contains a recipe for this, which is a bit more general than the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49880587/4042267) by [@pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault). It also uses a `set`:

Python 2:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse as filterfalse
```

Python 3:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
```

> ```
> def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
>     "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
>     # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
>     # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
>     seen = set()
>     seen_add = seen.add
>     if key is None:
>         for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
>             seen_add(element)
>             yield element
>     else:
>         for element in iterable:
>             k = key(element)
>             if k not in seen:
>                 seen_add(k)
>                 yield element
> ```

Use it with:

```
abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,0,3),(0,2,0), (2,4,5),(5,4,3), (0,4,1)]
Newlist = list(unique_everseen(abc, key=lambda x: x[0]))
print Newlist
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

This should be slightly faster because of the caching of the `set.add` method (only really relevant if your `abc` is large) and should also be more general because it makes the `key` function a parameter.

Apart from that, the same limitation I already mentioned in a comment applies: this only works if the first element of the tuple is actually hashable (which numbers, like in the given example, are, of course).

Comment: @A.S Fixed. In Python 2 it was called `ifilterfalse`. It still worked because in this case the `key` function was defined.

Answer (score 2):

@PatrickHaugh claims:

> but the question is explicitly about maintaining the order of the
>   tuples. I don't think there's a solution using groupby

I never miss an opportunity to (ab)use `groupby()`.  Here's my solution sans sorting (once or twice):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

abc = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (1, 0, 3), (0, 2, 0), (2, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3), (0, 4, 1)]

Newlist = list((lambda s: chain.from_iterable(g for f, g in groupby(abc, lambda k: s.get(k[0]) != s.setdefault(k[0], True)) if f))({}))

print(Newlist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
%
```

Answer (score 1):

To use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) correctly, the sequence must be sorted:

```
>>> [next(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(abc, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
[(0, 2, 0), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (5, 4, 3)]
```

or if you need that very exact order of your example (i.e. maintaining original order):

```
>>> [t[2:] for t in sorted([next(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted([(t[0], i)+t for i,t in enumerate(abc)]), lambda x:x[0])], key=lambda x:x[1])]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

the trick here is to add one field for keeping the original order to restore after the groupby() step.

Edit: even a bit shorter:

```
>>> [t[1:] for t in sorted([next(g)[1:] for k,g in groupby(sorted([(t[0], i)+t for i,t in enumerate(abc)]), lambda x:x[0])])]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 0), (5, 4, 3)]
```

Comment: That's true, but the question is explicitly about maintaining the order of the tuples. I don't think there's a solution using `groupby`

Comment: @fferri: I need the order of tuple as shown in expected output.

Comment: @A.S I updated my answer

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: there's always a solution with any tool =P

Comment: @fferri: Thank you for the extra effort. It works now.